# take last row from database and bind in datalist

Tags: c#, linq

moneyinfo table has many rows with same id, i want to take the last row i will use the below code below code and do it

```
var viewall3 = (from viewall4 in vfdet.MoneyInfos where viewall4.CustAccNo == id orderby viewall4.Moneyid descending select viewall4).FirstOrDefault();
```

but now i want to bind the last row in datalist, i have to use .ToList() to bind

```
var viewall3 = (from viewall4 in vfdet.MoneyInfos where viewall4.CustAccNo == id orderby viewall4.Moneyid descending select viewall4).ToList();

accdetai.DataSource = viewall3;

  accdetai.DataBind();
```

but if i use `.ToList()`  all the rows are showing i want only the last row please help

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault().ToList()`?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev No. :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var viewall3 = (from viewall4 in vfdet.MoneyInfos
                where viewall4.CustAccNo == id
                orderby viewall4.Moneyid descending
                select viewall4)
                .Take(1).ToList();
```

[`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence. So you take only 1 item from the start of your enumerable.

And personally I find this code more readable like this:

```
var viewall3 = vfdet.MoneyInfos.Where(i => i.CustAccNo == id)
                               .OrderByDescending(i => i.Moneyid)
                               .Take(1)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you so much i got what i want i was trying this for past 1 hour.. thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var dt2 = moneyinfo.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(1);
```

It will give you last record from your datatable